# How to construct a tree of particular shape with elements from a list

Tags: scheme

Given an s-expression `'((a . b) . (c . d))` and a list `'(e f g h)`, how can I traverse the s-expression create an s-expression with the same shape, but with elements taken from the list? E.g., for the s-expression and list above, the result would be `'((e . f) g . h)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traversing a tree of pairs in left to right order isn't particularly difficult, as **car** and **cdr** let you get to both sides, and **cons** can put things back together.  The tricky part in a problem like this is that to "replace" elements in the right hand side of a tree, you need to know how many of the available inputs you used when processing the left hand side of the tree.  So, here's a procedure **reshape** that takes a *template* (a tree with the *shape* that you want) and a *list* of elements to use in the new tree.  It returns as multiple values the new tree and any remaining elements from the list.  This means that in the recursive calls for a pair, you can easily obtain both the new left and right subtrees, along with the remaining elements.

```
(define (reshape template list)
  ;; Creates a tree shaped like TEMPLATE, but with 
  ;; elements taken from LIST.  Returns two values: 
  ;; the new tree, and a list of any remaining
  ;; elements from LIST.
  (if (not (pair? template))
      (values (first list) (rest list))
      (let-values (((left list) (reshape (car template) list)))
        (let-values (((right list) (reshape (cdr template) list)))
          (values (cons left right) list)))))
```

```
(reshape '((a . b) . (c . d)) '(e f g h))
;=> ((e . f) g . h)
;=> ()
```

```
(reshape '((a . b) . (c . d)) '(e f g h i j k))
;=> ((e . f) g . h)
;=> (i j k)          ; leftovers
```

Comment: I like `reshape` and `template`, they're better names, but please avoid using `list` as a parameter name. Also it's worth mentioning that `let-values` might not be available in some interpreters.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work for all inputs, for instance test it with the second example in my answer.

Comment: This method works great, but is it possible to only return the new tree?

Comment: @Jacob Use `let-values` to capture the results and return the first value. But be aware that this doesn't work for all inputs, for instance try this:  `(reshape '(a b) '(c d))`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez The list `(a b)` is the tree `(a b . '())`.  There are *three* things to replace, not two, so `(c d)` isn't enough elements.  I think that since the question asks about replacing in s-expressions, rather than lists, it's appropriate to consider trees rather than lists.

Comment: @Jacob yes, as Óscar said, you can use `let-values` or `call-with-values` to get both values and just return the first.  If you take that route, then you could make what I've called `reshape` a helper method inside the primary `reshape` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you want to create a new s-expression with the same shape of the s-expression given as the first parameter, but with the elements of the list from the second parameter.

If that's right, here's one possible solution using a list to save the point where we are in the replacement list and Racket's [`begin0`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._begin0%29%29) to keep the list updated (if that's not available in you interpreter use a `let`, as suggested by Chris and Joshua in the comments):

```
(define (transform sexp lst)
  (let loop ((sexp sexp))     ; the s-expression list to be traversed
    (cond ((null? sexp) '())  ; if it's empty, we're finished
          ((not (pair? sexp)) ; if it's an atom
           (begin0            ; then (alternatively: use a `let`)
             (car lst)        ; return first element in replacements list
             (set! lst (cdr lst)))) ; and update replacements to next element
          (else                         ; otherwise advance recursion
           (cons (loop (car sexp))      ; over both the `car` part of input
                 (loop (cdr sexp))))))) ; and the `cdr` part
```

For example:

```
(transform '((a . b) . (c . d)) '(e f g h))
=> '((e . f) g . h)

(transform '((a . b) (c d (x y) . z) . t) '(e f g h i j k m))
=> '((e . f) (g h (i j) . k) . m)
```

Comment: Even though I find the use of `set!` distasteful in general, I don't have a better solution at the moment. Still, it's better not to use `list-ref`. You can do something like `(let ((result (car lst))) (set! lst (cdr lst)) result)` instead. (Common Lisp has a `prog1` macro for that kind of thing in general, though in this specific case, its `pop` macro is even more direct.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I think it's a bit more elegant to simply have the function return multiple values (the new tree and the remaining elements from the input list).  Then you get all the information you need to continue from the recursive calls.  I've added an answer with that approach.

Comment: Even in this approach with mutable state, why use list-ref and an index?  Wouldn't updating lst (i.e., `(set! lst (rest lst))` be easier?  Then the element for the result is always available at the front of lst.

Comment: Ok guys, I updated my answer. Granted, `list-ref` was a late-night hack :P . We don't know if `begin0` is available in OP's interpreter, if not we can always use `let`, as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is similar to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27206921/1193075):

```
(define (transform sxp lst)
  (let loop ((sxp sxp))
    (cond ((null? sxp) sxp)
          ((pair? sxp) (cons (loop (car sxp)) (loop (cdr sxp))))
          (else (begin0 (car lst) (set! lst (cdr lst)))))))
```

then

```
> (transform '((a . b) . (c . d)) '(e f g h))
'((e . f) g . h)
```