# How to keep track of current position in a list while doing deep recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme, r5rs

what I'm trying to do is take a symbolic expression, and replace all of its 'leaves' with the numbers in a list from left to right, so the left-most leaf should be replaced with 1, the next 2, etc, etc.

This is the code I have currently (I'm using R5RS, and I'm trying not to use mutation)

```
(define subst
  (lambda (sexp num)
    (cond ((null? sexp) '())
          ((not (pair? sexp)) (car num))
          (else (cons (subst (car sexp) num)
                      (subst (cdr sexp) (cdr num)))))))

(define numbers (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
```

The output for:

```
(subst '(((a (d . e)) (b . c)) . (c . d)) numbers)
```

is:

```
'(((1 (2 . 3)) (2 . 3)) 2 . 3)
```

What I would like to be output is:

```
'(((1 (2 . 3)) (4 . 5)) 6 . 7)
```

I was thinking that I need to change num to cdr num in the previous recursion of subst when I come across and replace a leaf, but I don't see how I can do that without using set!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In the question marked duplicate the answers use procedures that aren't in r5rs which I specified I was using for my solution

Comment: My own [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27209078/201359) to that question is r5rs compatible, as long as you replace `begin0` with `let`. Take the time to read it and read the comments.

Comment: @IBOED2 My solution to that uses `let-values`, which is simply syntactic sugar around `call-with-values`.