# Replace Symbolic Expression with an Infinite Stream

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I am attempting to replace a given symbolic expression with a given infinite stream.
For example consider an infinite stream of multiplication of 2:

```
(define doubles
  (cons-stream 1 (s-map (lambda (x) (* x 2)) doubles)))
```

and assume my functions defining a stream are correct.

Now when i call my method to replace the symbolic expression i get the following:

```
(replace '((a . b) . (c . d)) doubles)
   --> ((1 . 1) 1 . 1)
```

Notice here, my recursive calls only ever replace my expressions with the 'start' of the infinite stream, i.e. the method cannot keep track of when to use the 'remaining' part of the stream.

The correct output should be:

> --> ((1 . 2) 4 . 8)

My current code to is as follows;

```
(define (replace s str)   (cond ((null? s) '())
        ((atom? s) (head str))
        (else (cons (replace (car s) str)
                    (replace (cdr s) str)))))
```

My question would then be; how could i go across the stream whilst calling my method recursivley?
thanks in advance.

Edit:

My attempt at using another method to calculate the remaining stream:

```
(define (replace s str)
  (cond ((null? s) '())
        ((atom? s) (head str))
        (else (cons (replace (car s) (get-stream s str))
                    (replace (cdr s) (get-stream s str))))))

(define (get-stream s str)
  (cond ((null? s) '())
        ((atom? s) (tail str))
        (else (get-stream (cdr s) str))))
```

This returns a new output of:

```
---> ((4 . 4) 4 . 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mutate str, otherwise it will keep on returning the first element. For example, using a `set!` statement:

```
(define (replace s str)
  (let loop ((s s))
    (cond ((null? s) s)
          ((pair? s) (cons (loop (car s)) (loop (cdr s))))
          (else      (begin0 
                       (stream-first str)
                       (set! str (stream-rest str)))))))
```

then

```
> (replace '((a . b) . (c . d)) doubles)
'((1 . 2) 4 . 8)
```

See also my remarks to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27206921/1193075).

Also, note that there is no `null` in your input structure so the test will never yield true.

**EDIT** Here's a version without `set!`, in standard Racket, which should be easy to port to R5RS:

```
(define (replace s str)
  (define-values (res _)
    (let loop ((s s) (str str))
      (cond ((null? s) (values s str))
            ((pair? s) (define-values (res1 str1) (loop (car s) str))
                       (define-values (res2 str2) (loop (cdr s) str1))
                       (values (cons res1 res2) str2))
            (else      (values (stream-first str) (stream-rest str))))))
  res)
```

Comment: Hello, this method works nicely. Would it be possible to do this without mutation, however? For example, defining another function that returns the transformed S-exp and the remaining stream values? As i'm trying to keep it as functional as possible

Comment: Yes but it will not necessarily look better. You'd have to work with `let-values` then. Which implementation are you using (Racket, MIT, Chicken, ...)?

Comment: I am using Racket R5RS for this,