# How to achieve tail recursion on a tree-shaped data structure

Tags: algorithm, recursion, scheme, racket, tail-recursion

I'm using Racket but the question would apply to any Scheme, where tail recursion is supported.

I'm familiar with the traditional pattern for achieving tail recursion on a flat list, which is roughly like so:

```
(define (func x [acc null])
  (if (null? x)
      acc
      (func (cdr x) (cons (do-something-to (car x)) acc))))
```

In this case, `func` is in tail position.

But when I'm working with a tree, i.e., a list with recursively nested lists, I end up doing recursive descent with `map` like so:

```
(define (func2 x)
  (cond
    [(atom? x) (do-something-to x)]
    [(list? x) (map func2 x)]))
```

This works, but `func2` is no longer in tail position.

Could you — and if so, how would you — rewrite `func2` in a tail-recursive way?

(Leaving aside the question of whether it improves performance, which is not the question I'm asking.)

Comment: Continuation passing style is another option.  I don't have time to post a full answer right now, but [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27207177/1281433) to [Replacing a symbol in a symbolic expression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27205618/1281433) shows a tail recursive approach (by virtue of CPS) to traversing (and replacing in) a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was already correctly stated and explained in the other answer, there's no advantage of using tail recursion on this. But, as you were interested in the way it would be done, here it is a `deep-map` function I have implemented once. The code is cleaner if you're satisfied with the mirrored list.

```
(define deep-map
  (λ (f lst)
    (let tail-rec ([stack `(,lst)] [acc '(())])
      ;(displayln (~a "Stack: " stack " / Acc: " acc))
      (cond [(null? (car stack))
             (if (null? (cdr stack))
                 (car acc)
                 (tail-rec (cdr stack)
                           `(,(append (cadr acc) `(,(car acc))) . ,(cddr acc))))]
            ;; The first element is a list and is being put on the stack
            [(list? (caar stack))
             (tail-rec `(,(caar stack) . (,(cdr (car stack)) . ,(cdr stack)))
                       `(() . ,acc))]
            ;; Process next element
            [else (tail-rec `(,(cdar stack) . ,(cdr stack)) 
                            `(,(append (car acc) `(,(f (caar stack)))) . ,(cdr acc)))]
            ))))
```

A simple example:

```
> (deep-map add1 '(1 ((2) 3)))
Stack: ((1 ((2) 3))) / Acc: (())
Stack: ((((2) 3))) / Acc: ((2))
Stack: (((2) 3) ()) / Acc: (() (2))
Stack: ((2) (3) ()) / Acc: (() () (2))
Stack: (() (3) ()) / Acc: ((3) () (2))
Stack: ((3) ()) / Acc: (((3)) (2))
Stack: (() ()) / Acc: (((3) 4) (2))
Stack: (()) / Acc: ((2 ((3) 4)))
'(2 ((3) 4))
```

Comment: Regarding performance, some quick tests in DrRacket show that `deep-map` is about an order of magnitude slower than the simple recursive-descent loop.

Answer (score 2):

You technically "can", by introducing an accumulator that acts as a stack. Your function would only be done when the stack is empty.

However, this has the same memory usage requirements as using the function call stack (i.e., non-tail recursion), so usually you don't gain anything by doing that.

Comment: Except that your accumulator can be "infinite" and your stack can't.

Comment: That's implementation-dependent. For example, if you implement continuations by using CPS-transformation instead of stack copying, your call stack would actually reside in the heap, and not be subject to the limitations of the CPU stack.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer: Even without the CPS hijinks Chris mentioned, there's actually no reason to assume that the heap is bigger than the stack.  In theory at least, you can use a linker switch to reserve 2^wordsize bytes of VM for the stack, and the OS will page it in as necessary.  The real limit may be slightly lower, and OS-dependent.